# How do I check for the default value of a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER value in Azure SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL database. In this database, I have a stored procedure that will be responsible for inserting email addresses. I need to get the ID of an email address from the table. If the email address doesn't exist, I need to create a new record in the table and get the ID. In an effort to do this, I currently have:

```
DECLARE @ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
SELECT @ID=[ID] FROM [dbo].[EmailAddresses] WHERE [EmailAddress]=@EmailAddress

-- Identify if a new email address needs to be created
IF @ID = CAST(CAST(0 AS BINARY) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
BEGIN
    PRINT N'Insert a new record into EmailAddresses. Then, assign the ID variable'
    PRINT N'I never get here'
END
```

I know how to insert records in to a table. My problem is the line with `IF @ID...`. I do not know, nor can I find what the default value of a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` variable is. For that reason, the condition on my `IF` statement is always false.

What is the default value of a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` variable in Azure SQL and how do I do an `IF` on it?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you get in SSMS if the `@EmailAddress` does not exist, `SELECT [ID] FROM [dbo].[EmailAddresses] WHERE [EmailAddress]=@EmailAddress`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not know, nor can I find what the default value of a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER variable is.

NULL.  All TSQL variables are nullable, and default to NULL.

And a variable assignment in a SELECT statement will assign the variable for each row in the result.  And if there are no rows in the result, the value of the variable will not be changed.

So

```
iF @ID is null
begin
 . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it a little and just use NOT EXISTS

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT [ID] FROM [dbo].[EmailAddresses] WHERE [EmailAddress]=@EmailAddress)
BEGIN
    PRINT N'Insert a new record into EmailAddresses. Then, assign the ID variable'
    PRINT N'I never get here'
END
```